# Alternative to compiling against weblogic.jar?

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, maven-3

I have inherited an old project that using `ant` to build against `weblogic.jar`. I am moving this into a more modern `maven` based build environment and I don't want to check in `weblogic.jar` ( which is 34MB ) into my private artifact repository and I don't want to add it to my local repository either. I am not sure what it is using from this, the project is one monolithic code base over 500,000 lines of code.

We won't actually have Weblogic on our local development machines, we are deploying to remote virtual machines to test because of corporate network topology to get the services our application needs to talk to.

**What alternative do I have to building against `weblogic.jar`.**

Comment: What classes inside it do you need? The Java EE 6 APIs seem to be available in `central`: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/6.0 (The usual practice would be setting them as `<scope>provided</scope>`.) If you need a WebLogic-specific class, then the best practice should be keeping it in a company-wide repo configured in the POM or `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Using system scope is usually considered a bad practice. However, I would say in the case of `weblogic.jar`, using system scope makes sense. The reason is that the the `weblogic.jar` does not contains all the classes provided by WLS installation. If you open `weblogic.jar` and take a look at the `MANIFEST.MF` file inside, it contains a long list of jar files in the `Class-Path:` entry. These jar references are all using relative path. It means that if you put the `weblogic.jar` into the maven repository, the relative path is broken and you need to a lot more WLS jar files into your maven repository.

The catch is that if your system-scoped dependency points to the `weblogic.jar` in your WLS installation, you need to standardize the WLS installation directory for all your developers. Otherwise your build is not portable in other developers' machine.

Comment: Can I ask you, is the weblogic.jar MANIFEST.MF classpath editable? I mean is it possible to add a jar to the classpath after the weblogic.jar installation. I don't have control over it, and people who have says its not possible. For some reason, I don't believe them!

Comment: Once WLS is installed, it is within your control. You can do whatever you want. However, it is not recommended. You are not supposed to stuck your own jar files into weblogic.jar MANIFEST.MF file. I cannot think of a reason why you want to do that. Besides, you have to think of patching/upgrade from Oracle, which might overwrite your changes. There are plenty other ways to add your jar file to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Since maven downloads everything it tries to resolve into your local repository the only way (afaik) would be wrapping the existing ant task using [maven-ant-task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html).

Personally I would prefer to add the weblogic stuff into the maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put it into your local repo, you could refer to it using system-scoped dependency, in which case you'd just refer to it from your disk. I'm not sure why that would be better option, but since you asked for it, you might have a solid reason.

However assuming you don't want to use weblogic.jar at all: it's not really possible to say what alternatives to building against it you have without knowing what you need from it. That needs to be found out first. If you use weblogic-specific stuff, you do need the reference.